# YOLOv5 SKU-110 Pre-trained weights

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, transfer-learning, pre-trained-model, yolov5

I want to use Yolov5 to annotate a video file containing products on supermarket shelves. There is a huge dataset (over 12GiB) [SKU-110K](https://github.com/eg4000/SKU110K_CVPR19), introduced in CVPR 2019, including thousands of images of many supermarket shelves for training Yolo. I'm looking for pre-trained YOLO weights for SKU-110. I searched in its [Github repository](https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/blob/master/data/SKU-110K.yaml) and elsewhere but could not get anything.

- Does anyone knows has ever YOLOv5 trained for SKU-110K?
- If yes,
  where can I find its weights file?

Answer (score 1):

There are no official SKU-110K Yolov5 weights (nor any privately trained and open sourced either what I have seen) but you can train your own Yolov5 model on this dataset by a simple command:

```bash
python train.py --data SKU-110K.yaml
```

this will automatically download, prepare the data and start training

Comment: Thank you for your answer; It was evident that I can simply train my Yolov5 model with SKU-110K. But don't forget it is almost 12Gib for download and takes lots of time even for fine-tuning; This is why I highlighted "weights" in my question.